# PHPMailer (SetFrom and AddReplyTo)

Tags: php, phpmailer

code:

```
class email extends main{
    function email($to, $to_name, $subject, $message, $type, $schoolTitle, $schoolEmail, $attachments){
        $this->to = $to;    
        $this->to_name = $to_name;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->schoolTitle = $schoolTitle;
        $this->schoolEmail = $schoolEmail;
        $this->attachments = $attachments;
    }
    function connect(){
        require_once PLUGINS.'PHPMailer-20160322/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail->isSMTP();
        $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $this->mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
        $this->mail->Host = "**********";
        $this->mail->Port = **;
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
        //$mail->Sender="************";
        $this->mail->Username = "**************";
        $this->mail->Password = "**************";

    }
    function sendSingle(){
    //this is used in the bulk emailer when the connect it called so we can send multiple emails from 1 connection
    $this->mail->addAddress($this->to, $this->to_name);
    $this->mail->Subject = $this->subject;
    $this->mail->msgHTML($this->getMessage());
    $this->mail->AltBody = strip_tags($this->message);
    $this->mail->setFrom($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
    $this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);                    
    foreach($this->attachments as $item){           
        $this->mail->addAttachment($item);
    }

    if (!$this->mail->send()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**Result I want:**

I want to be able to use the `testEmail` and `testTitle`

```
$this->schoolEmail= "chris.beckett@testing.co.uk";
$this->schoolTitle= "Chris Beckett";
$this->mail->setFrom($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
$this->mail->AddReplyTo($this->schoolEmail, $this->schoolTitle);
```

**What I've tried and worked:**

I don't understand why the `testTitle` works but when I try and pass in the `testEmail` the email doesn't send or it will send but it won't have the parameters of `from:` or `reply to:`

```
$this->schoolEmail= "chris.beckett@testing.co.uk";
$this->schoolTitle= "Chris Beckett";
$this->mail->setFrom('name@yourdomain.com', $this->schoolTitle);
$this->mail->AddReplyTo('name@yourdomain.com', $this->schoolTitle);
```

Debug Info showed that it worked but the email not showing up in my inbox:

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Chris Beckett <chris.beckett@testing.co.uk>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Reply-To: Chris Beckett <chris.beckett@testing.co.uk>
```

Could anyone explain what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of class is `$this`?

Comment: Have you tried enabling the debugging of PHPMailer? It will literally tell you what it's doing when connected to the sending mail server

Comment: @KIKOSoftware based on the title and tags, it's an instance of PHPMailer

Comment: @Machavity it looks more like a class *containing* or `extending` PHPMailer original class(es).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Updated my question with more code

Comment: @Machavity Yes and it says it works but it doesn't actually show up in my inbox but when i remove the passed parameters then it does show up.

Comment: I guess you intentionally left out the `To:` field in the debug info? I still don't get your question. Are you using 'test' just as an example? Because I don't see those properties in your class.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Yes that's just an example

Comment: Well, unless you provide the real code, that doesn't work, we cannot tell what's going on.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - Updated have a look now

Comment: Yes, that should work. If it doesn't try the debug info. Please note that the fact that you receive an email, or not, is not a good way to test PHPmailer. For all you know the mail server might have blocked the mail.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - That was the answer! If you want to add a answer below in more detail, i'll tick it as the answer. It's because I was using my contact email as the test email. I've put a block for spamming the email.

Comment: Ah, it's always the little things that get you. I've followed your advice.

Comment: People complain if I put this comment in as an answer, so I deleted it.

Comment: to be fair KIKO, your answer was just the comment, but the *actual* answer is that the OP should check their mail settings and that (as you said) not sending emails does not mean `PHPMailer` failed. :-p